# Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword and onAuthStateChanged Realtime Database logging issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a webpage using HTML5 CCS etc, where it uses a authentication process using firebase for users. Its my first time ever working on firebase, so i still have no idea how to correctly code using it.

I manually add a admin user on firebase, so i can use those credentials to log in to the webpage. In the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` i used a code to log into the console some information about credentials, but whats happening is that while it does work (the authentication). The only way it logs info into the console is when i don't redirect the user to another page using the `onAuthStateChanged` (basically not using it at all).

Basically it authenticates correctly, but its doesn't log the info in the realtime database unless i remove the `onAuthStateChanged`.

Here is the code

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;

    const dt = new Date();
    update(ref(database, 'users/' + user.uid), {
      Email: email,
      Password: password,
      Last_Login: dt
    })

    alert('Usuario ingresado!')
    location.href = 'test.html'
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;

    alert(errorMessage)
  });

});

const user = auth.currentUser;
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    location.href = 'test.html'
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

I heard this process is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Calls to Firebase (and most modern cloud APIs) are asynchronous, since they may take some time to complete. But as soon as the user is signed in, the local `onAuthStateChanged` will be called - which interrupts the write to the database.

If the user always actively signs in to this page (so you always call `signIn...`), then you don't need the `onAuthStateChanged` handler and can just include the navigation code in the then:

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;

    const dt = new Date();
    update(ref(database, 'users/' + user.uid), {
      Email: email,
      Password: password,
      Last_Login: dt
    }).then(() => {
      location.href = 'test.html'; // 
    })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;

    alert(errorMessage)
  });
});
```